# Github shows can merge automatically, no conflicts, but Github Actions shows merge conflict

Tags: git, github-actions

On my deployment branch, I am 2 commits behind a development branch. Github shows this branch is 2 commits behind - when I click into it into compare changes page, it shows the green tick "Able to merge. These branches can be automatically merged."

However, in my Github Actions workflow, I have the following, which should just rebase the deployment branch.

```
jobs:
  rebase:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: deployment
          ssh-key: ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}
      - name: Rebase UAT onto main
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git fetch origin dev
          git rebase origin/dev
```

When I do this locally with `git rebase origin/dev`, I get `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/deployment`. But in the Github Actions runner, I get

```
Auto-merging .github/workflows/main.yml
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .github/workflows/main.yml
warning: Cannot merge binary files: .pnp.cjs (HEAD vs. 1806843 (Deployment specific commit))
Auto-merging .pnp.cjs
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .pnp.cjs
warning: Cannot merge binary files: .pnp.loader.mjs (HEAD vs. 1806843 (Deployment specific commit))
...
```

What could be the reason, and how might I resolve this?

Comment: `checkout` does a shallow clone of just one commit by default. If the branch you want to rebase has more than one commit, rebase will fail because the commits aren't there. Try `fetch-depth: 0` as an option on `checkout` to fetch the entire history.

Comment: David, have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: @AdamJensen I suspect Ben's comment above will resolve it, but I opted to write shell code entirely from scratch, instead of learning how this particular action's syntax works. Can share if you'd like

Comment: @DavidMin sorry, I forgot to post an update: Ben's solution works for me and I have no longer issues with rebasing using GitHub actions. Thank you guys!